# iOS: How to handle the new SKErrorCodes introduced in iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

My app is seeing more failed in app purchases of late and I think it's tied to the new errors introduced in iOS 9.3 (SKErrorCloudServicePermissionDenied and SKErrorCloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed) has anyone else been having issues? Does anyone have a good solution on how to handle these?

Comment: do you mind posting your code so we can help you